# Are Amazon VPC private IPs constant?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, private-ip

I have a VPC set up and working on Amazon and one EC2 instance talks to another via its private IP. Will this IP remain constant to that EC2 instance through out multiple reboots? Is there anyway to hard code or reserve a private IP to an EC2 instance in a Virtual Private Cloud?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You absolutely can specify the private IP address when you start an instance - it's at the bottom of the page in the GUI when you launch an instance, or you can specify it with the --private-ip-address option if you start with the commandline aws utility:-

```
aws ec2 run-instance <...options...> --private-ip-address 10.1.2.3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can request an IP when you create the instance. If you do this, it will persist through reboots.

Answer (score 0):

The Amazon Private IP Address will remain constant throughout the machine Life Time, even during the reboots . So no need to worry for that.